# How to: Create a Right Click Function in HTML5 that changes the Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contextmenu, right-click

**I do have a question about HTML5.** Think of *Dropbox*, where it is possible to right click in the main content. Doing this, you can do things like "Create a new folder". How is that possible? The content is changed during runtime. When you right click and create a new folder, it appears and it is also possible to change the name of the folder. And the best thing: it automatically saves everything you do! How do they do that?

In short:

- How is it possible to create custom right click options?
- How can you save changes that are made with this options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect right button on mousedown. try this:

```
$('#element').on('mousedown',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if(e.button==2)
      {
        alert("right button clicked"); 
        // do your stuff here.
        }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The "custom right click options" are created in the client's browser, preferably using JavaScript.

The changes are saved by sending post ( or put/delete ) requests to the server.

Comment: Could you please go into more details? Are there any tutorials, documents or functions that can help me to find the information I need?

Comment: @Exception yes, the web is overloaded with tutorials and lessons. You need to learn JavaScript and how events work, how HTTP works as well as back-end development.

Comment: You are welcome. Keep in mind that you will probably not learn those things overnight.

Comment: Oh I know, I am not new to coding. ;-)